# Display data in a Tk text box without the ['\n']

Tags: python, python-3.4, tk-toolkit

this should take a line and display it in a txt box, this should work but there must be a mistake that i can't see.

```
def show_indiv():
    with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r') as f:
     event = combo_event.get()
     indivcombo = combo_individual.get()  
     if event == 'Event 1' and indivcombo == 'Individual 1': 
           with open('data/tournamentdatae1.txt', 'r') as f:
               for i,line in enumerate(f,1):
                    if i == 21: 
                        indiv_txt.insert(0.0, line)
```

Comment: What box are we talking about here?

Comment: just a text box    team_1txt = Text(root, width=10, height=1)
team_1txt.place(x=100, y=210)

Comment: insert the `line`, not `get_all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are unnecessarily nesting your loops, and opening the same file thrice. But your real problem is that you inserted `get_all`; the list of lines, instead of the line. My suggestion:

```
def show_team():    
    if event == 'Event 1': 
        with open('data/tournamentdatae1.txt', 'r') as f: 
            for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
                if i == 1: 
                    team_1txt.insert(0.0, line)
                elif i == 2: 
                    team_2txt.insert(0.0, line)



team_1txt = Text(root, width=10, height=1)
team_1txt.place(x=100, y=210)

team_2txt = Text(root, width=10, height=1)
team_2txt.place(x=206, y=210)
```

Comment: thank you that works well, u saved me a lot of hassle and messing around with the code.

Comment: could you possibly help with this im trying to save data onto line 21 in a file but it saves onto line 1 insead any ideas>>>???

Comment: if event == 'Event 1' and indivcombo == 'Individual 1': 
            with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
                for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                    if i == 22:
                       individualmain = individual.get() 
                       f.writelines(individualmain)
                       f.writelines("\n")

Comment: Since I don't see your code, I can't help you. Make a new question with your full script (if it's not too long) and your new problem.